# comparing strings in shell

Tags: bash

I have a code where it is checking first column from a file which is as_of_date. then from hive query i am storing the result in a variable A1. the column is string as well. but when i am comparing in if loop even if both the strings are same it's going into else loop as both are not equal. Can anyone correct me where i went wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

AS_OF_DATE=$(awk -F\|  '{var1=$1; print var1}' a.txt)

A1=$(HIVE -S -e "select max(date) from db.table;")

declare -p A1 AS_OF_DATE

if [[ "$AS_OF_DATE" == "$A1" ]]; then 
echo "true"
else [[ "$AS_OF_DATE" != "$A1" || "$AS_OF_DATE" == "NULL" ]]; 
echo  'False'
fi
```

Now even if the dates are matching the false if printing and this is the result of declare-p

```
AS_OF_DATE - "2021-03-01"
A1 - "2021-03-01
```

Can someone suggest where i am going wrong.

Comment: Your code contains several syntax errors. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste exactly the code you run on your system. Don't re-type your code as this may introduce or remove errors. Also copy&paste the output you get. Variable names are case-sensitive. `AS_OF_DATE` is not the same as `AS_OF_dATE`.

Comment: @bodo have pasted the exact code. and that's the result which i am getting of declare in the console.. the file is having value 2021-03-01 and it's a pipe delimited file which i am reading

Comment: `this is the result of declare-p` can't be, `declare -p` should print `declare var=something`. Are you sure you are using bash? Please add `set -x` on top of the script and post the output.

Comment: The `[[ "$AS_OF_DATE" != "$A1" || "$AS_OF_DATE" == "NULL" ]]` after `else` is useless. Do you mean `elif [[ "$AS_OF_DATE" != "$A1" || "$AS_OF_DATE" == "NULL" ]]; then`? But even this could be replaced with a simple `else` (without the additional condition). If the `else` (or `elif`)  is reached, the condition `[[ "$AS_OF_DATE" == "$A1" ]]` must be false, so you don't need to check the negated condition. If you want to force the output `false` if `"$AS_OF_DATE" == "NULL"`even if it might match `"$AS"`, then you would have to check for `"NULL"` first.

Comment: I'd suggest you to print these 2 variables in hex for debugging: `printf '%s' "$AS_OF_DATE" | od -v -A n -t x1` and `printf '%s' "$A1" | od -v -A n -t x1`.

Comment: @Darkman.. the AS_OF DATE VALUE IN HEX IS COMING AS 32 30 32 31 2D 30 33 2D 33 30.. THE SAME IS THE INITIALS FOR VARIABLE A1 but it is getting appended with warning messages  bcoz of which mismatch is happening. can someone suggest a way to resolve the issue

Comment: Please put the output that you're seeing in your question. Try running the script I've provided below.

Comment: @Darkman is there something syntactically wrong in this .. awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$"}{gsub(/[\r\n]/,"",$0)} 1')".. the warning messages are getting added in the resu;t of hive query and is getting stored as A1.. [[WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might solve your problem.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

AS_OF_DATE="$(awk -F\|  '{print $1; exit}' a.txt)"

A1="$(hive -S -e "select max(date) from db.table;" | awk '{print; exit}')"

declare -p A1 AS_OF_DATE

printf '%s' "${AS_OF_DATE}" | od -v -A n -t x1
printf '%s' "${A1}" | od -v -A n -t x1

if [[ "${AS_OF_DATE}" == "${A1}" ]]; then 
    echo 'True'
else
    echo 'False'
fi
```